# Move image left to right using surfaceview android

Tags: android

I am trying to understand using surfaceview. I want an image to move from left to right using surfaceview. Currently image is drawn but I am unable to make it move. Where should I call the variables x1 and y1. Also how could I call the invalidate() method, I want to make the image move from left to right repeatedly. Thanks

```
public class GameBoardTwo extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap bitmap1;

private SurfaceHolder holder;
int x1, y1;



public GameBoardTwo(Context context) {

    super(context);

    holder = getHolder();
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);
    init();

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);

            drawSomething(c);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        }



        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,

                                   int width, int height) {

        }

    });



}

   private void init(){

      x1 = 0;

       y1 = 100;


}



protected void drawSomething(Canvas canvas) {


   canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);



 if(x1 < canvas.getWidth()){

     x1 += 5;
 }

 else{
     x1 = 0;
 }

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x1, y1, null);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use thread/runnable inteface and override run(). Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void run(){
    while(true){
         drawSomething(c);//c is your locked canvas
         try{
             Thread.sleep(50)
         } catch(Exception e){}

    }

}
```